# Loading string to array of array

Tags: javascript

I am getting a set of arrays in string format which looks like

```
[49,16,135],[51,16,140],[50,18,150]
```

Now I need to save them in an array of arrays. I tried it like

```js
let array = [];
let str = '[49,16,135],[51,16,140],[50,18,150]';
array = str.split('[]');
    
console.log(array);
```

but it is creating only one array including all string as an element while I need to have

```
array = [[49,16,135],[51,16,140],[50,18,150]]
```

Comment: It's returning one string because the substring `[]` does not appear in the `str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add array delimiters to each end of the string, then use `JSON.parse`:

```js
const str = '[49,16,135],[51,16,140],[50,18,150]';
const json = '[' + str + ']';
const array = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: you were faster! :D

Answer (score 2):

You are splitting it incorrectly, in the example, it will only split of there is a `[]` in the string

You can create a valid JSON syntax and parse it instead like so,

```js
let str = '[49,16,135],[51,16,140],[50,18,150]';
let array = JSON.parse(`[${str}]`);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Yeah @Taplar I copied the snippet from question for faster response, Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could achieve this is by using a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor. This method allows you to "loosely" pass your array.

```js
const strArr = "[49,16,135],[51,16,140],[50,18,150]",
arr = Function(`return [${strArr}]`)();

console.log(arr);
```